# Command "ps -a" does not show all processes?

Tags: ps

I used the command

```
ps -A
```

to see all running processes. However, even though I have a LibreOffice Writer opened in the background, the command does not list LibreOffice as a running process. Even

```
 ps -A | grep libre
```

does not return anything. How is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

It is `soffice.bin` you are looking for.

With and without "calc" open:

```
$ ps -A | grep office
 6718 ?        00:00:00 soffice.bin
$ ps -A | grep office
$
```